# How to set border for events in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling

I've one `Label` in my custom `FlowPanel` which implements `HasDoubleClickHandlers`.

```
    final Label label = new Label("Click here to write");
    label.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            clicked();
        }
    });
    final CustomFlowPanel customFlowPanel=new CustomFlowPanel();
    customFlowPanel.addDoubleClickHandler(new DoubleClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onDoubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource() instanceof FlowPanel) {
                doubleClicked();
            }
        }
    });
    custoFlowPanel.add(label);
```

The problem is when i double click to the label `doubleClicked()` should not execute.
How to prevent executing `doubleClicked()` when label is double clicked?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just check the DoubleClickEvent if the label was clicked and if not you call     doubleClicked().

```
customFlowPanel.addDoubleClickHandler(new DoubleClickHandler() {           
      @Override         
      public void onDoubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {             
          Element clicked = event.getNativeEvent();
          if (!clicked.Equals(label.getElement())
          {
              doubleClicked();         
          }
      }     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet, but try adding a double click handler on the label and use  [Event.stopPropagation()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/dom/client/NativeEvent.html#stopPropagation()) on it. This prevents the event from being propagated to the parent.